# Primefaces 4.0 - jquery.js "Member not found" error on IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces

When I browse my primefaces application on Internet Explorer 11, I am getting this error "Member not found".

When I debug the web site, The `Exception` is thrown on `jquery.js.jsf, Line: 25, Column 37861`.

Why I get this error? It is showing correctly on Mozilla FireFox's and Chrome's latest versions.

Comment: You're getting this on all the pages ?
Try to do a minimal page and see if the problem still exists.
If it's gone, it's more probably that your code is causing this..

Comment: _I found the problem's temporary solution. for IE11 adding compability view meta tag to head._               **<h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>**

Comment: @HatemAlimam Yeah, I am getting this error on all pages. The problem is caused by jquery.js.jsf file.

Comment: This is **not** a temporary solution, this is a MUST sometimes.. I wouldn't use `Edge` as a value, I would focus on one version, for example in my project to get IE into some sense I include this in my template.. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` with IE8 option, this way I know one mode would operate. [see more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)

Comment: One note I have noticed that your IE version is 11, somehow 11 version has a specific case.. read it in the previous link